# Get capture date from mapbox satellite imagery

Tags: mapbox

I am following the mapbox tutorial [here](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/static/). I have the static map displaying nicely inside of my web page. I would like to include a capture date on the image provided by map box.

I am using the `mapbox.satellite` `mapId`. So, my url looks like this:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.satellite/${lng},${lat},19/1000x700.jpg90?access_token=${accessToken}
```

My access token is provided by Digital Globe in a trial account. Does anyone know if the capture date is available, and if so, how to retrieve it?

Comment: I have been trying to find out this information. I asked on their "support forum" and after three attempts finally got the answer: "We think that's a great idea and we've implemented it for our Landsat Live data pipeline which you can read about here: https://www.mapbox.com/blog/satellite-metadata/. No plans just yet to include this for our higher zoom levels but it has been considered." I have asked why they would not do it, no response. I am aware of how many billions of tiles global coverage at zoom 19 involves, but there are techniques for dealing with this, so am am at a loss to explain.