# Possible to get year/date for the satellite photos/data tiles?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Oftentimes when I browse Leaflet maps with Mapbox.com data (using some sort of open, standardized database), I notice that the satellite images and/or data are out of date. It would be extremely useful to somehow get to see the year/date when the current tile/map/view was shot/obtained/photographed/created/edited, in order to determine how out of date with reality a given location is.

Is this data available? If so, how would I best display it in Leaflet? I imagine some sort of subtle year/date text in the middle of each "area" or something, or maybe allow me to right-click anywhere to get a little pop-up telling me this info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346450/get-capture-date-from-mapbox-satellite-imagery

Comment: Well, that page is worthless too because there is no solution there either.

Comment: C'mon, follow the links in there, folks. https://blog.mapbox.com/metadata-vector-tiles-for-imagery-d8b37812f6c3 - https://www.mapbox.com/bites/00145/#7/-18.334/139.131

Comment: I read that. I don't understand why you link to it? Is it saying something to you that I'm missing?